# How to distribute percentage amount items

Tags: sql-server

I have a table structure that is storing Order. Let's say I have an order in which customer demands 3 `Items` of different `Qty` and different  `Unit Price` for each Item.
Shopkeeper gives him `25000` discount on all `items` but later on customer came and ask to remove one `item` from order so I want to get the `amount` of `discount` that was applicable on that `item` so that `amount` of `discount` applicable on that `item` could also be adjusted from order.

```
CREATE TABLE SALE_MASTER
(
ORDER_NUMBER VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
DISCOUNT_AMOUNT NUMERIC
)

INSERT INTO SALE_MASTER VALUES ('SO-100-ORD-19', 25000);

CREATE TABLE SALE_DETAIL
(
ORDER_NUMBER VARCHAR(50),
ITEM_NAME VARCHAR(250),
QUANTITY INT,
PRICE NUMERIC,
CONSTRAINT FK_SALE_MASTER FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_NUMBER)
REFERENCES SALE_MASTER(ORDER_NUMBER)
)
INSERT INTO SALE_DETAIL VALUES ('SO-100-ORD-19', 'Double Bed', 5, 70000);
INSERT INTO SALE_DETAIL VALUES ('SO-100-ORD-19', 'Sofa', 5, 10000);
INSERT INTO SALE_DETAIL VALUES ('SO-100-ORD-19', 'Dining Table', 1, 50000);

SELECT * FROM SALE_MASTER
SELECT ITEM_NAME, QUANTITY, PRICE, (DISCOUNT_AMOUNT/(QUANTITY*PRICE)) FROM SALE_DETAIL, SALE_MASTER
WHERE SALE_DETAIL.ORDER_NUMBER = SALE_MASTER.ORDER_NUMBER
```

Comment: Expected output would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your case correctly, you need to calculate the discount for one unit of your currency (25 000 / 450 000) and then do all calculations:

```
;
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        SALE_MASTER.ORDER_NUMBER,
        SUM(SALE_DETAIL.QUANTITY * SALE_DETAIL.PRICE) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT,
        SALE_MASTER.DISCOUNT_AMOUNT
    FROM SALE_DETAIL, SALE_MASTER
    WHERE SALE_DETAIL.ORDER_NUMBER = SALE_MASTER.ORDER_NUMBER
    GROUP BY SALE_MASTER.ORDER_NUMBER, SALE_MASTER.DISCOUNT_AMOUNT
)
SELECT 
    SALE_DETAIL.ITEM_NAME, 
    SALE_DETAIL.QUANTITY, 
    SALE_DETAIL.PRICE, 
    (SALE_DETAIL.QUANTITY * SALE_DETAIL.PRICE) * (cte.DISCOUNT_AMOUNT / cte.TOTAL_AMOUNT) AS ITEM_DISCOUNT_FOR_ALL_ITEMS,
    SALE_DETAIL.PRICE * (cte.DISCOUNT_AMOUNT / cte.TOTAL_AMOUNT) AS ITEM_DISCOUNT_FOR_ONE_ITEM
FROM SALE_DETAIL, cte
WHERE SALE_DETAIL.ORDER_NUMBER = cte.ORDER_NUMBER
```

Output:

```
ITEM_NAME      QUANTITY PRICE   ITEM_DISCOUNT_FOR_ALL_ITEMS  ITEM_DISCOUNT_FOR_ONE_ITEM
Double Bed     5        70000   19444.444444                 3888.888889
Sofa           5        10000   2777.777778                  555.555556
Dining Table   1        50000   2777.777778                  2777.777778
```